# Simple math-to-english calculator

Tags: java, exception

I'm currently taking a basic programming course. The teacher refuses to look at my code and attempts to guess the question I'm asking, and then answer that (incorrect) question. The basics of this is, it's supposed to take an equation, like 5 * 6, and output "Five times six equals 30," with the answer just being a number. The code I have right now is as such:

```
package mainPackage;
import java.util.*;


public class Main 
{
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the equation");
    String input = scan.nextLine();

    String space = " ";

    int firstSpace = 0;
    int secondSpace = 0;

    int numInt1 = 0;
    int numInt2 = 0;

    String a = "0";
    char b = 'a';
    String c = "0";

    firstSpace = input.indexOf(space);


    String sub = input.substring((firstSpace + 1), input.length());

    secondSpace = sub.indexOf(space);

    a = input.substring(firstSpace--);
    b = input.charAt(firstSpace++);
    c = input.substring(secondSpace++);

    numInt1 = Integer.parseInt(a);
    numInt2 = Integer.parseInt(c);


    String num1 = "";
    String op = "";
    String num2 = "";

    switch (numInt1)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            num1 = "Zero";
        }

        case 1:
        {
            num1 = "One";
        }

        case 2:
        {
            num1 = "Two";
        }

        case 3:
        {
            num1 = "Three";
        }

        case 4:
        {
            num1 = "Four";
        }

        case 5:
        {
            num1 = "Five";
        }

        case 6:
        {
            num1 = "Six";
        }

        case 7:
        {
            num1 = "Seven";
        }

        case 8:
        {
            num1 = "Eight";
        }

        case 9:
        {
            num1 = "Nine";
        }
    }

    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
    System.out.println(c);

}
}
```

She has told us that between each number and operand, she WILL put a space. So rather than 5/6, it would be 5 / 6, and that we only have to do it for 0 to 9, but still have to detect if she puts a two digit number, and print invalid number. This part I know how to do. The problem arises when I try to run this. No errors are showing up in the lines, but when I run it, I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " * 6"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at mainPackage.Main.main(Main.java:44)
```

This ends up being this line:

```
numInt1 = Integer.parseInt(a);
```

When removing them, the code prints out something like this:

```
"5
 * 6
 * 6"
```

Would anyone know why this is happening? I feel as though it is something painfully obvious that I missed.

EDIT: Thank you all so much for your quick replies. She never taught us the split method. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site. Have you tried debugging? If you use Eclipse, you can run this in debug mode, set breakpoints, and step through the execution step by step.

Comment: `a = input.substring(firstSpace--);` should be `a = input.substring(0, firstSpace--);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using  `String.split(String regex)` function

```
String arr[] = input.split("\\s+");// splitting input by space 

numInt1 = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);//5
numInt2 = Integer.parseInt(arr[2]);//6
char b = arr[1].charAt(0);//*
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, I am so glad you all mentioned this split method. Never heard of it, never got taught it, but it works perfectly for some things I was having trouble with in other programs as well.

Answer (score 1):

First I think you should get familiar with the debugger. It's very useful and there is almost no way one can code a program larger than 20 lines without the need of it ;)

Now take into consideration two things here: substring(beginIndex) returns a sub-string beginning from that index (0 based) to the end of the string.
This is why `"5 * 6".substring(1)` will return `" * 6"` (1 is the "position"/index of the first space in the string "5 * 6", because it's 0-based).
That is why you are getting an Exception parsing the expression into an Integer value.
The other thing is, that firstSpace++ or firstSpace-- will increase and decrease the value of firstSpace, respectively, and will do it AFTER the rest of the command.
So actually:

```
a = input.substring(firstSpace--);
b = input.charAt(firstSpace++);
c = input.substring(secondSpace++);
```

is equivalent to something like that:

```
a = input.substring(firstSpace);
firstSpace = firstSpace - 1;
b = input.charAt(firstSpace);
firstSpace = firstSpace + 1;
c = input.substring(firstSpace);
firstSpace = firstSpace - 1;
```

And you lost what you wanted to achieve.
There are several solutions to your problems. Some of them are suggested above. Some use tools that are a bit more advanced, but you can also solve the problems without other help methods (longer and uglier, but will still work).
My advice is get used to using the debugger, it could help you find out the problem very quickly in this situation.

Comment: I cannot believe I forgot that it adds one to the variable, not just for the method. Thank you for mentioning this!

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the input is a number, a space, an operator, a space and a number, then that means the length of the input is five characters. Anything other than that is wrong. You can then also check whether these five characters match the given format.

In general, you should always verify user input before passing it to methods that expect a certain input. The user could enter anything and it's up to your program to ensure the input adheres to the desired format.

Comment: I threw an if (input.length > 5) System.exit(0); in there, thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely in these lines.

```
a = input.substring(firstSpace--);
b = input.charAt(firstSpace++);
```

There are two problems that I see.  First the use of -- and ++ is actually changing the value of firstSpace.  It looks like b will contain the space instead of the arithmetic operator.  You can help yourself figure out what is going on by sprinkling some System.out.println() messages in there to see what is happening to your index variables.

Second, the substring method with a single parameter creates a substring from the given index to the end of the string.  I think you may really want to do something like:

```
a = input.substring(0, firstSpace-1);
```

This will give you the substring from the beginning of input to the character before the first space.

Comment: Ahh, it was from the index to the end? For some reason, I assumed it was just that specific index, thanks!